# Submitting a Spark job using Shell script file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to submit a Spark Job from a shell script.

Its a simple script with just spark-submit command. I am trying to give an argument to my Main function through the spark-submit command, But when i try executing the shell file the job is failing with Error :

```
scala.MatchError: rma (of class java.lang.String)
```

As i have used match-case in my code.

This is the content of my Shell Script

```
    #adsName=$1
    spark-submit --class TestQuery --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 12G --executor-memory 8G --executor-cores 4 \
--num-executors 100 --files /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/conf/hive-site.xml \
--jars /users/myuser/config-1.2.0.jar \
/users/myuser/jars/adsoptimization_2.11-0.1.jar \
xyz
```

So 'xyz' is the string i am passing in the command. currently i have hard-coded it still its not working i wanted to pass this dynamically as an argument to the shell file.

My code in the main function:

```
args(0) match  {
  case "str1" => TestQuery(spark).runstr1
  case "xyz" => TestQuery(spark).runxyz
  case "str2" => TestQuery(spark).runstr2
  case "str3" => TestQuery(spark).runstr3
}
```

so the 'xyz' string that i am passing will come in args(0) (and then i am calling the function defined in my case class by passing the spark session object as the args)

So here the ask is how to simply make the spark job run via shell script

Comment: Can you do `args.foreach(println)` **before** the pattern matching expression? You'll know what is passed as `args`. Also, start your shell script with `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=1` to see what exactly `spark-submit` executes. That should give you enough to hunt down the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

That error comes when you pass in a value with no matching pattern.  You passed in `rma` but you didn't have a case for it. Just add this...

```
args(0) match  {
  case "str1" => TestQuery(spark).runstr1
  case "xyz" => TestQuery(spark).runxyz
  case "str2" => TestQuery(spark).runstr2
  case "str3" => TestQuery(spark).runstr3
  case _ => TestQuery(spark).someDefaultDefined
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your spark-submit that I can see.  And your error is easy to replicate by giving a value with no matching pattern.  Perhaps your args(0) is not catching anything, you should be using a debugger, or you could just print out what is in args(0) old school style.  Then we can look into it further.  Actually can you just post your whole main method?

Comment: Thats ok. i was able to fix this by taking the result or agrs(0) into a val & then matching it

Comment: That's what I thought but you said it was correct argument.  Don't forget to mark the answer pls